# How to to set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value for a column

Tags: laravel, database-migration, laravel-6

Using laravel migrations, I want to set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value for created_at column.

I don't know if the error is issued by migrating laravel from 5.7 to 6

Here is my migration file:

```
Schema::create('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
        $table->collate = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';

        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index('idx_user_id');
        $table->string('ip', 50);
        $table->string('user_agent', 255);
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

    });
```

And the error in console:

> Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) default character set utf8mb4
>   collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' ' at line 1")

Mysql version: `5.7.23`

PHP version: `7.2.10`

Laravel version: `6.0.2`

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here. Why would you need the default value for created_at? Shouldn't this column get it's value when an actual entity is created?

Comment: have you tried now() instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ?

Comment: @zlatan yes sure this is possible, but I m used to let mysql managing it.

Comment: @danish-khan-I yes I tried it, the same error. The thing I don't understand is that this code is running perfectly before I migrate to laravel 6

Comment: then why don't you just set it default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP using phpmyadmin ? it will be easire

Comment: try `$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)'));`

Comment: actually, I found that the problem is not in 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' but in 'default' method. I also get the error for this line:  $table->string('ip', 50)->default('127.0.0.1');

Comment: The error was in laravel version 6.0.2  composer upadate to v6.0.3 fixed the problem